# Issue with batching the project

Tags: android, image, batch-file, icons, emulation

I'm trying to create an icon for our Android app. The png is created and was put into the proper folder of my project so it can be batched with the batch file. Up to now, everything was fine, but I did a new image I wanted to test on the emulator, but now, although the image is in the appropriate folder and my batch file configured correctly (it works for our 2 other identical projects), it won't take the new image and the previous one I tested keeps being batched despite being deleted (the .apk and key generated with the previous image were deleted as well) and also the app was removed from the emulator. Any ideas what could cause this? Also for some odd reason (I haven't touched the code of the project for well over a week), I ended up with this error "LanguageURL cannot be resolved or is not a field", I managed to fix it by copying the same line from the same project. Would that have anything to do with it?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to me before... Are you sure the icon fits the specs?

Look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Comment: Actually they do. The only thing I've changed from the previous image I did, was add a very thin layer of gloss....I did notice it now that It does say to not use a glossy, but it's barely visible. Thanks, I'll try it without the gloss.

Comment: well I'll be damned. It was the thin layer of gloss the issue. Did a new basic icon and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do I only have to click Yes when asked Was This Post useful to you? (Sry about that; still a n00b around these parks)

Comment: There should be a grey tick outline to the left of the answer (It turns green after you click it). You can just click it and that is all. I am also a n00b with SO:-). It is good for the people looking for the answer to the same problem as they can find it easily then.